# Follow set example doesn't follow any rules?

Tags: parsing, grammar, ambiguous-grammar

1. S → asg
2. S → if C then S E
3. C → bool
4. E → else S
5. E → λ

all the lower case and the λ are terminal symbols

I need help deriving the follow set of this grammar. I normally do not have trouble with these problems and I know the rules, but when I practiced this example from my book this is the only thing I could get:

```
Follow(S) = {$} U Follow(E) 
Follow(C) = 
Follow(E) =
```

Comment: S can be followed by E, whose FIRST set includes `else`. And C  can be followed by `then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.cs.uaf.edu/~cs331/notes/FirstFollow.pdf:

> To compute FOLLOW(A) for all nonterminals A, apply the following rules until nothing can be added to any FOLLOW set:
>
> 1. Place $ in FOLLOW(S), where S is the start symbol and $ is the input right endmarker.
> 2. If there is a production A ⇒ αΒβ, then everything in FIRST(β), except for ε, is placed in FOLLOW(B).
> 3. If there is a production A ⇒ αΒ, or a production A ⇒ αΒβ where FIRST(β) contains ε (i.e., β ⇒ε), then everything in FOLLOW(A) is in FOLLOW(B).

Assuming `S` is the start symbol in your grammar and `λ` represents an empty string, we get:

- `{$} ⊆ Follow(S)` by rule 1.
- `(First(E) \ {λ}) ⊆ Follow(S)` by rule 2 / production 2.
- `Follow(E) ⊆ Follow(S)` by rule 3 / production 4.
- `(First(then S E) \ {λ}) ⊆ Follow(C)` by rule 2 / production 2.
- `Follow(S) ⊆ Follow(E)` by rule 3 / production 2.

`First(then S E)` is just `then` (because it's terminal), so we have `{then} ⊆ Follow(C)`.

This is the only constraint on `Follow(C)`, so the smallest set that satisfies it is:

```
Follow(C) = {then}
```

Because we have `Follow(E) ⊆ Follow(S)` and `Follow(S) ⊆ Follow(E)`, it follows (hah) that they're equal:

```
Follow(E) = Follow(S)
```

Finally we have

```
Follow(S) = {$} ∪ (First(E) \ {λ})
```

Fortunately `First(E)` is easy because `E` only has two productions, one of which is empty and the other starts with a terminal symbol:

```
First(E) = {λ, else}
```

Therefore

```
Follow(S) = {$, else}
```

and

```
Follow(E) = {$, else}
```